# How can divide every <tr> element to the different lines of listview while fetching jsoup html parsing?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, html-parsing

It should to fetch data that is in `<tr>` element. I can fetch successfully with these code but it fetch every data of `<tr>` to the one single of listview line. It should to split every data of `<tr>` in different single line. Just tried to make for iteration but it doesn't work successfully.

This is my program show data:
[![
This is my program show data][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5mFX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5mFX.png)

This is the website that include data:

[image: This is the website that show data]

It should get and show data like the website show. Please help me for it.

This is my program codes in `Android Studio`.

```
public class Alapli extends Activity {
private ListView lv;
public ArrayList liste= new ArrayList();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private static String URL="http://zonguldakism.saglik.gov.tr/TR,15189/alapli--nobetci-eczane.html";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.alapli);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste);
new dataFetch().execute();

//Admob Banner BottomAd reklam
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.addView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

 // Geri tuşu için actionbar aktif etmek
 ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
 ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
private class dataFetch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(Alapli.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Alaplı");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor..");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(30 * 1000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .get();
            Elements pharmacy = doc.select("tr:nth-child(n)");

    for (int i = 0; i < pharmacy.size(); i++) {
            liste.add("\n" + pharmacy.text());
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the data, why it contains html tags, and why can't you use `WebView`?

Comment: It's pharmacy on duty list for a ctiy. I want only pharmacy information from html tag. I don't want use webview becasue I don't want fetch all website. I want use only these information in my app. When website update data, it will update in my app also.

Comment: WebView can be used to view any type of HTML data, not just a some website. That includes html text you get from a file.

Comment: I use WebView in another project. Firstly, this website is not mine. Secondly I want fetch these data only and I want it automatically update when they change it. I don't know WebView do this automatically.

Comment: Obviously not, it won't do that automatically unless "they" make a separate resource which will serve auto-updated page only with data on it. But it doesn't mean you have to hard-parse raw HTML yourself, which was my entire point from the very beginning. Use WebView, or explain why it doesn't fit and why you need to manually parse everything.

Comment: For example this website has menu top of the page and banner. So I dont want get it. If I use webview it will fetch it. I want only <table> for this reason. This is the website: http://zonguldakism.saglik.gov.tr/TR,15189/alapli--nobetci-eczane.html

Comment: Again, for the n-th time: WebView can be used to display arbitrary HTML data given to it, just like any browser engine. If you managed to extract the required data, then you can display it in WebView. If you don't then explain why you are failing.